# permission of associated subgrid in crm

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, subgrid

I have a (CRM) grid that has associated view (a) I need to add another associated view (b) to the **same grid** and to give different view permission (some users will see 'a' and some will see 'b') can I control these permissions on my associated grids

Comment: @ArunVinoth changed

Comment: Basically what’s the difference btw two views? Same entity? Users with different roles??

Comment: Same Entity different roles, some will see associated view A and other associated view B

Comment: I think you mean custom views with extra filters? What are those filters?

Comment: There may be better way to use CRM security concepts. That’s why am asking..

Comment: Otherwise, have 2 subgrids for 2 views & in JS we can show hide based on user security roles

Comment: @ArunVinoth answer to *What are those filters?* -> different business units. one will be able to watch associated view A and the other Associated B, I think maybe the solution with two grids changing in JS according to business unit is the only way.. is that right?

Comment: Shouldn't BU level Read pemission take care of data segregation ? Why make two views ?

Comment: Different BU owned records should not be visible in subgrid of user from another BU. May be you have to tweak the security role.. this is how CRM works

Comment: @Alex the basic grid is the same the associated views are edited differently according to different users/roles

Comment: Are you currently adding BU in filter criteria of view? It’s wrong design.

Comment: @ArunVinoth nope, now I'm checking options and possibility before changing  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your requirement, it looks like you don’t need two views & switch hit.

User A should have a security role A which will filter the data what he can see & cant see.

In security role A modify the Read privilege to BU level - half amber (now it may be full green - Org level)

The same security role A to User B (if they are from different BU) will work as it is. Basically role A has to be there in all BUs individually.